# How to play sound with a scheduled task but not logged

Tags: windows, audio, scheduled-tasks

I made a simple console application that only plays an embeded wav.

If i configure an scheduled task when i'm logged in works fine.

If i'm not logged in, the task apparently runs, but there is no sound.

What can i do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem making a windows service application instead of a console application and using [naudio library](http://nuget.org/packages/NAudio/1.5.6-beta).